# Regex for random character and digits

Tags: c#

Can anybody help. I'm trying to get information after "duration" from html strings with this random character and digits

"duration": "PT59M33S"

"duration": "PT1H4M24S

here's what I'm currently using but it's only getting the first duration.

```
(duration\W\W \W(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])([A-Z0-9]+))
```

Comment: What is it exactly you want as an output

Comment: Those aren't random at all. This is the [ISO601 duration  format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Comment: Also, not sure why you have the two lookaheads `(?=`. Do you want to filter some cases? the `([A-Z0-9]+)` should take everything you need.

Comment: the output I want is to get  PT59M33S and PT1H4M24S
I will just gonna replace with format time after I get that result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh I just knew it. do you know how I can get it and convert to Format time 00:00:00.00?

Comment: Is there any obligation to use Regex?